# Recursive function with array of variables

Tags: recursion, list-manipulation

I am trying to create a recursive function which works with an increasing array of variables.
Since the formula is quite complex, i will try to simplify my example to the core of my problem.

The initial value of the array should be $f[\{1\}]=2$ and all other arrays with a single element should have the value $0$.

When an array of size $n$ is given to the function, it will reduce the size of the array to $n-1$ by dropping the first element. 
So if an array with the values $\{0,0,1,0,2\}$ is given, it will reduce it to $\{0,1,0,2\}$, or more generally the array $\{r_5 ,r_4 ,r_3 ,r_2 ,r_1\}$ will be reduced to $\{r_4 ,r_3 ,r_2 ,r_1\}$. The computation in this case should be:
$$f[\{r_5 ,r_4 ,r_3 ,r_2 ,r_1\}]=(r_4 -1)*f[\{r_4 -1,r_3 ,r_2 ,r_1\}]+(r_3 -1)*f[\{r_4 ,r_3 -1,r_2 ,r_1\}]+(r_2 -1)*f[\{r_4 ,r_3 ,r_2 -1,r_1\}]+(r_1 -1)*f[\{r_4 ,r_3 ,r_2 ,r_1-1\}]$$

To speed up the computation, the function should memorize results and arrays containing a negative element ($-1$) should not be computed and instead given the value 0.

My attempt so far starts with:

```
f[r_] := f[r] = With[{n = Length[r], k = Rest[r]}
```

...

To change the values of the $r_i$, I generated a For-Loop (from $1$ to $n$) containing:

```
f[ReplacePart[k, -i -> Part[k, -i] - 1]]
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd let the pattern matcher do most of the work. First, the recursion start:

```
f[{1}] = 2
f[{_}] = 0
```

Now the actual recursion:

```
f[{x_, rest__}] :=
   f[{x, rest}] = If[Min[{x,rest}]<0, 0,
                     ({rest}-1).Table[f[ReplacePart[{rest},
                                                    k -> ({rest}[[k]]-1)]],
                                      {k, 1, Length[{rest}]}]]
```

Explanation:

`_` matches any single expression, therefore `{_}` matches every list containing a single expression. However for `f[{1}]` you have a better match from the first definition, therefore that is used in that case.

If you have more than one element in the list, the second term matches: The `_` matches the first expression, and `rest__` matches the other expressions, replacing each occurrence of `rest` on the right hand side by that expression sequence.

`{rest}-1` subtracts 1 from any element of `{rest}`, and `list1.list2` multiplies corresponding elements of the two lists, and adds the results.

The rest should be clear, I think.

Comment: You're missing the nonnegative condition and the memoization, but otherwise it looks ok :)

Comment: @TeakeNutma: I've now added both. Thank you for noting.

Comment: I think the code is missing the closing bracket of the if-condition. It seems very fast and i hope i can extend it to match the actual formula. :)

Comment: @kon: Indeed, that closing bracket was missing (reminder to self: don't skip testing, even for simple changes!). Thank you for noting, and for the accept.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a refactoring of celtschk's code; it is both shorter and faster:

```
f[{1}] = 2;
f[{_}] = 0;
f[x_List] /; Min[x] < 0 = 0;
mem : f[{_, x__}] := mem =
  ({x} - 1).Table[f @ MapAt[# - 1 &, {x}, i], {i, Length @ {x}}]
```

Test:

```
{4, 6, 5, 8, 5, 2, 5, 1, 5, 9, 0, 5, 3, 5, 2, 7, 3} // f // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1.312075, 22727314469007948800}
> ```

Comment: You seem to be a little bit absent lately. I hope everything is well and that you are just harvesting trees in the Oregon woods ?

Comment: @eldo Thanks for noticing.  I am well, just a bit busy with things, and also enjoying the last of the warm sunny weather for the year.  If last year is an indicator I'll be a bit absent until January, but I'll still be available when needed.